# I am trying to make an applet ReadOnly in Siebel. I am using Aspect BC ReadOnly property

Tags: siebel

But Aspect BC ReadOnly is not working. Can Aspect ReadOnly be used to make entire view ReadOnly.

I am using something like this:

In BC user props,

```
Name  - Aspect BC ReadOnly: Aspect1       
Value - Field1
```

In Applet User props,

```
Name  - View Aspect: MyView1
value - Aspect1
```

This should make My Applet Readonly in MyView1 when Aspect1 value i.e Field1 value is "Y".

P.S: `Field1` is a calculated value and this gets evaluated to "Y".

But this is not working, Is there any special case when this will not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found out from metalinks that this Aspect property can be used only for baseclass CSSBCBase class. But My BC's base class is something different, Is there any other way to implement this for BCs whose base class is not CSSBCBase class.

Comment: Next time, please tell us what Siebel version you're using, it may determine what answers will be useful for you and which ones won't! Also, this has nothing to do with eScript - please tag your questions properly, that way everybody can find them easily. And last but not least, welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, because I never used this "Aspect ReadOnly" user property (is it something new in Siebel 8.x?)... But I'm afraid that you're answering yourself:

> this Aspect property can be used only for baseclass CSSBCBase class. But My BC's base class is something different

Maybe you can do something like this:

1. Add a new calculated field to your BC, with the following expression: `IIf([Field1]='Y' AND GetProfileAttr('ActiveViewName')='MyView1', 'Y', 'N')`
2. Add the user property `BC Read Only Field` to your BC. The value would be the name of the calculated field in step 1.

Ta-da! :) That would make the BC read only when your Field1 is true, but only if the active view is MyView1. If you're not in a view (i.e. scripting, workflows, etc.), the BC should be editable.

If you need the applet to be readonly, but not the BC, you could use instead `Applet Read Only Field`, although I'm not sure if it works with all applets or it depends on the class.